# Issue validation failed error for Azure App Registration (even in sample application from quickstart)?

Tags: asp.net, azure, oauth-2.0, webforms, azure-web-app-service

I am working on extending an existing .Net 4.7 WebForms web application hosted on Azure with OAuth.
To accomplish this, I created a new App Registration in Azure and tried to integrate it using OWIN with the following code

```
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            // ResponseType is set to request the code id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
            }
        }
    ) ;
```

The authentication was successful, but on redirect back to my application I got the following error:

> IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not
> match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: '[PII is hidden]' or
> validationParameters.ValidIssuers: '[PII is hidden]'

To isolate the problem from my existing web application I went to Azure portal and downloaded the sample application using Quickstart option from the menu:

[image: Menu at Azure portal]

This resulted in a very similar error:

> Error: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: 'System.String'.
> Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: 'System.String' or
> validationParameters.ValidIssuers: 'System.String'.

From that I concluded that something is wrong with my App Registration potentially. I tried to do a research and found some topics to set `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` from `null` to `2` in the manifest settings. However this setting was already correct and the portal disallowed me to set to anything else (to downgrade the version).

Any ideas what else I could try?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently what I missed is that authentication happened on OAuth server, but the issue validation takes place directly in your application once the user is authenticated. This is set by `TokenValidationParameters` in `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` class.

Add the following line to `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` to bypass that validation (only do it for test purposes!):

```
 TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { ValidateIssuer = false }
```